# Elasticsearch js query with must and must_not

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I am trying to get a query to run with both must and must_not, but have not had any luck with the syntax I am attempting. I see a lot of people on StackOverflow using quotes on both sides like they would be in a Curl call, but this is straight out of a node application.

I will show the query that does work, and I am simply trying to add what I **do not** want to be included in the outcome. In either case, because this is just trash data that is on a local dev environment, the outcome should match.

First the working query:

```
client.search({
    index: config.ES_INDEX,
    type: "issue",
    body: {
        query: {
            match: {
               issue_state: 'Closed'
            }
        },
        size: 1000
    }

}).then(function(resp){
    console.log(util.inspect(resp, {showHidden: false, depth: null}));
}).catch(function(err){
    console.log('Failed to search. ' + err.message);
});
```

Output:

```
{ took: 5,
timed_out: false,
  _shards: { total: 5, successful: 5, failed: 0 },
  hits:
   { total: 1,
     max_score: 1,
     hits:
      [ { _index: 'noc_tool',
          _type: 'issue',
          _id: 'Sy2IQFMLe',
          _score: 1,
          _source:
           { job_name: 'Job Name 1',
             is_maintenance: 'no',
             servicenow_id: 'lkjjklh',
             type: 'Chase',
             start_time: '1970-01-01T23:15:00.000Z',
             maint_reminder: null,
             update_duration: '4 Hours',
             location: 'Test Group',
             issue_state: 'Closed',
             notes: [ { created_on: 1484063571941, body: 'lkjlkjhlkj' } ],
             emailService: { lastEmailAt: 1484237594114 },
             created_on: 1484063571941,
             updated_on: 1484240538801,
             reason: 'because I want to' } } ] } }
```

Now, the failed query:

```
client.search({
    index: config.ES_INDEX,
    type: "issue",
    body: {
        query: {
            bool: {
                must: [
                    {
                        term: {
                            issue_state: 'Closed'
                        }
                    }
                ],
                must_not: [
                    {
                        term: {
                            is_maintenance: 'yes'
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        size: 1000
    }

}).then(function(resp){
    console.log(util.inspect(resp, {showHidden: false, depth: null}));
}).catch(function(err){
    console.log('Failed to search. ' + err.message);
});
```

Output:

```
{ took: 6,
timed_out: false,
  _shards: { total: 5, successful: 5, failed: 0 },
  hits: { total: 0, max_score: null, hits: [] } }
```

Any help here would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a little "reverse logic" but here is what is working..

```
return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    client.search({
        index: config.ES_INDEX,
        type: "issue",
        body: {
            query: {
                bool: {
                    must:[
                        {
                            match: {
                                issue_state: 'Closed'
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            match: {
                                is_maintenance: 'no'
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            size: 1000
        }

    }).then(function (resp) {
        resolve (resp.hits.hits);
    }).catch(function (err) {
        reject('Failed to search. ' + err.message);
    });
```